# Print the first 128 prime numbers without using any reserved words

Tags: code-golf

The obvious solution would be to just print them as a string, but is it possible to write a shorter code?

Requirements:

1. No input should be processed, and the output should be in the form of `2 3 5 7 11 13 ...` etc.
2. No reserved words in the language are used at all
3. The language should at least allow structured programming, and have reserved words (otherwise point 2 would be moot).

<sub>first I had exclusively C/C++ in mind, but extended the question while still trying to prevent cheating</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately for me, Tcl has no reserved words.

Comment: This challenge is quite old and while clear at the time it was asked we now have different standards for clarity that have to be met.  I've closed it for that reason.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### C, 60 chars

The "no keywords" limitation doesn't matter here. I'm pretty sure that improving it, if possible, won't be done by adding keywords.

```
n=2;main(m){n<720&&main(m<2?printf("%d ",n),n:n%m?m-1:n++);}
```

Alternate version:
The output isn't as nice, but I like the `printf` abuse.

```
n=2;main(m){n<720&&main(m<2?printf("%*d",n,n):n%m?m-1:n++);}
```

The trick in both solutions is to merge two loops (implemented by recursion) into one.
`n` is the next potential prime, `m` the next potential divisor.
In each recursive call, we either increment `n` (while setting `m` to its previous value) or decrement `m`.

Answer (score 8):

### Python, 108 chars

Python was not made for this challenge.  Wanna `print`?  That's reserved.  Well, how about we use `stdout`?  Well, that's gonna cost an `import`... you guessed it, reserved.  Well... I'm on unix, so I can open up the file descriptor 1, which happens to be stdout.  Hack!

Man, and iteration?  Nothing but `eval`.  No loops, of course, but we can't even define a function with `def` or `lambda`. And to add insult to injury, we can't even use list comprehension!  I always look for an excuse to use things like `map(p.__mod__,...)` in code golf... comprehension is always better.  Until now, that is.

```
p=1
eval(compile("p+=1;open('/dev/fd/1','w').write('%s '%p*all(map(p.__mod__,range(2,p))));"*720,'','exec'))
```

Now, you might complain that `exec` is a keyword, even though I didn't use the keyword (I didn't even `eval` an `exec`).  Well, here's a 117-character solution which doesn't use `'exec'`.

```
p=2
s="eval('('+s*(p<720)+')',open('/dev/fd/1','w').write('%s '%p*all(map(p.__mod__,range(2,p)))),{'p':p+1})";eval(s)
```

Comment: print isn't reserved in Python3 :) you can use `__import__`, but that's gonna cost characters

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (80 chars)

```
eval((s=Array(719)).join("s[j=++n]?j:"+s.join("s[j+=n]=")+"r+=n+' ';"),r="",n=1)
```

Run in console of your webbrowser.

Used a prime sieve, which turned out to be very condensed.

Answer (score 5):

### C, 87 chars

```
d;p(n){--d<2||n%d&&p(n);}r(n){p(d=n);d<2&&printf("%d\n",n);++n<720&&r(n);}main(){r(2);}
```

(I tried to write it in a more functional style, but my inability to use `return` kind of killed that plan.)

Answer (score 4):

### C, 183 chars

```
#define q j*j<k?i%p[j++]||(i++,j=0):printf("%d\n",p[j=0,k++]=i++)
#define A q;q;q;q;q;q;q;q
#define B A;A;A;A;A;A;A;A
#define C B;B;B;B;B;B;B
main(){int i=2,j=0,k=0,p[999];C;C;C;C;C;}
```

Well, here's a quick first attempt.  I believe this should satisfy the requirements.  I'm using simple trial division to find the primes and an unrolled loop constructed using the preprocessor to iterate it until I've found enough of them.  The number of repetitions has been tweaked so that exactly 128 primes are printed.

Answer (score 4):

### C, 134 chars

Here's an alternate solution that tries to avoid using words as much as possible, reserved or otherwise:

```
main(i){i<9?main(2953216):i>4097?--i&4094?i/4096%(i%4096)?main(i):
main((i/4096-1)*4097):printf("%d\n",i>>12,main((i/4096-1)*4097)):0;}
```

All it uses is `printf` and `main` with a single argument.

Answer (score 4):

#### *Mathematica* 50 characters

I'm not sure how to interpret "reserved words" for *Mathematica* but I want to play so I'll take it to mean doing without built-in functions to generate primes or test for primality.

```
Fold[#2Cases[#/#2,1|_Rational]&,#,#]&@Range[2,719]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 72 characters

```hs
main=putStrLn.unwords$take 128[show p|p<-[2..],all((>0).mod p)[2..p-1]]
```

Admittedly, avoiding keywords isn't too difficult in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 31 bytes

```
x,1_&&/720#'!'x:24\234925135391
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/79CxzBeTU3f3MhAWV1RvcLKyCTGyNjE0sjU0NjU2NLw/38A)