# All primes from 0 to 1000

Tags: code-golf, number, tips, primes, c

Is it possible to make this C code smaller? It prints out all primes from 0 to 1000.

**C, 89 chars**

```c
int i,p,c;for(i=2;i<1e3;i++){c=0;for(p=2;p<i;p++)if(i%p==0)c++;if(c==0)printf("%u\n",i);}
```

Comment: Just to pre-empt some "We don't want language-specific challenges" downvotes, [asking for help golfing down some code is on-topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724/8478) and a different story than challenges.

Comment: Do we need to preserve the algorithm, or only the end result?

Comment: I'd start i at 2 to be strictly accurate, since this prints 0 and 1.

Comment: are you trying to make the code execute faster or trying to use less characters in the source code?

Comment: Since you're asking for assistance with golf, it would be helpful to include the character count of your current solution in your post (I make it as 89).

Comment: There is a better algorithm. Check Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**<s>59</s> 57 bytes**

Based on @feersum solution but the primality check can be golfed further

```
for(int p=1,d;d=p++%999;d||printf("%d\n",p))for(;p%d--;);
```

Edited based on Runer112's comments

Comment: The bound check can be golfed a bit more: `d=p++%999`. Otherwise, this looks pretty airtight golfing job!

Answer (score 10):

## 67 bytes

In C there's no real alternative to trial division, but it can certainly be golfed a bit.

```
for(int p=1,d;p++<999;d&&printf("%d\n",p))for(d=p;--d>1;)d=p%d?d:1;
```

Requires C99 initial declarations, which saves 1 byte.

Answer (score 6):

*(I wrote this not realizing the size limitations on integers in C, so it's likely not actually useful for shortening the code.)*

First, a word about algorithm. Before golfing your code, you should think about the best overall strategy to get the result.

You're checking primality by doing trial division -- testing each potential divisor `p` of `i`. That's costly in characters because it takes two loops. So, testing primality without a loop is likely to save characters.

An often shorter approach is to use [Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem): the number `n` is prime if and only if

```
fact(n-1)%n == n-1
```

where `fact` is the factorial function. Since you're testing all possible `n` from `1` to `1000`, it's easy to avoid implementing factorial by keeping track of the running product `P` and updating it by `P*=n` after each loop. Here's a [Python implementation of this strategy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/20260) to print primes up to a million.

Alternatively, the fact that your program only has to be right up to 1000 opens up another strategy: the [Fermat primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test). For some `a`, every prime `n` satisfies

```
pow(a,n-1)%n == 1
```

Unfortunately, some composites `n` also pass this test for some `a`. These are called [Fermat pseudoprimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime). But, `a=2` and `a=3` don't fail together until `n=1105`, so they suffice for your purpose of checking primes until 1000. (If 1000 were instead 100, you'd be able to use only `a=2`.) So, we check primality with (ungolfed code)

```
pow(2,n-1)%n == 1 and pow(3,n-1)%n == 1
```

This also fails to recognize primes 2 and 3, so those would need to be special-cased.

Are these approaches shorter? I don't know because I don't code in C. But, they're ideas you should try before you settle on a piece of code to start eking out characters.

Comment: Wilson's theorem is not useful in C because `int`s are 32-bit. Same goes for Fermat's.

Comment: @feersum Oh, shoot. That's a problem for the factorials too. Is there a big-int type?

Comment: @xnor Not built-in.

Comment: if one defines `fact(int n, int m) { return (n==0) ? 1 : (n*f(n-1)) % m; }` then the result won't overflow a 32 bit integer for even fairly large values of `n`.  (`m` is the modulus)

Comment: @anorton I think you mean `(n*fact(n-1,m)) % m`. Which highlights the problem: you cannot avoid the recursion in the implementation of `fact` because `m` will be different for each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: @hvd You're right that I meant `n*fact(n-1, m)%m`, but I don't see how that's a problem.  We *want* `m` to be the same for each recursive step (which is what this program does); I'm not sure, but I think that a good compiler should optimize the recursion to an iterative solution, too.

Comment: @anorton Yes, but then you've still got a nested loop. [Here's a simple version with the recursion manually converted to a loop](http://ideone.com/nqzdTh), so that it's easier to see: there's an outer loop in `main`, and an inner loop in `fact`. This answer suggests avoiding the inner loop by remembering `fact(n - 1)` from the previous iteration and just multiplying that by `n`, but that's no longer possible when you don't calculate `fact(n - 1)`, when you only calculate `fact(n - 1) % m`.

Answer (score 4):

## <s>78</s> 77 characters

(Just applied some tricks learned in other languages.)

```c
int i=0,p,c;for(;i<1e3;i++){c=0;for(p=2;p<i;)c+=i%p++<1;c||printf("%u\n",i);}
```

### 76 characters in C99 mode

```c
for(int i=0,p,c;i<1e3;i++){c=0;for(p=2;p<i;)c+=i%p++<1;c||printf("%u\n",i);}
```

Answer (score 2):

### 58 chars (or 61 for a complete program)

Another reuse of [my answer to a similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5818/3544).
**EDIT**: stand-alone code piece, no function to call.

```
for(int m,n=2;n<999;m>1?m=n%m--?m:n++:printf("%d\n",m=n));
```

Complete program:

```
n=2;main(m){n<999&&main(m<2?printf("%d\n",n),n:n%m?m-1:n++);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## <s>67</s> 64 bytes

Inspired by Alchymist's solution :

```
int i=1,p;for(;i++<1e3;p-i||printf("%d\n",i)){p=1;while(i%++p);}
```